# How do I display a download bar in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, download-manager

I recently started using Firefox Quantum at work. Having previously used Google Chrome, it feels a bit strange having file downloads shown in a separate window. If possible, I would like to view my downloads as a status bar, similar to Chrome.

[image: Chrome's download bar]

How can I display my file downloads with a status bar in Firefox Quantum?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, deep customization of the UI like you're hoping for is not currently possible with Firefox Quantum, as we're rebuilding its add-on APIs from the ground up.

A proper solution will only be possible once [Bug 1215064](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215064) is resolved.

In the meantime, add-on authors could achieve something *similar* to the above by using the [downloads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads) API in a [sidebar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars) to list and manage current downloads. To get a bottom-bar, add-ons could use a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts) to inject an `<iframe>` with that information into pages, but that's a bit of a hack.

Comment: any change now?